# Nswag specify multiple Response Example in Same Http Status Code?

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, nswag, redoc

i need to set some response example which have same http Status Code by C#.

i have studied the post
https://blog.rsuter.com/nswag-tutorial-implement-a-custom-operation-processor-to-define-redoc-code-samples/

but i still have no idea.

how can i do ?
please give me some hint ...

```
// i want to create json , like this.
responses:
        '404':
          description: please , let It worked...
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/TestModel'
              examples:
                success :
                  summary: Example of a successful response
                  value:
                    code : 1
                    message : "test message 1"
                success2 :
                  summary: Example of a successful response2
                  value:
                    code : 2
                    message: "test message 2"
```

update :
i use NSwag , like this
i need to let code 404 have two Example response

```
/// <summary></summary>
/// <remarks></remarks>
/// <response code="200"></response>
/// <response code="404">Message 1</response>
/// <response code="404">Message 2</response>   // <---- error will occur , 
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CreateIdentificationResponse), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), 404)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), 404)]
public IActionResult Post(){
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i get the answer ~~~

```
// using
// [ExampleAttribute (nameof(MyError.MyErrorFieldName))]

public class ExampleAttribute : OpenApiOperationProcessorAttribute
{
    public ExampleAttribute(string errorField)
        : base(typeof(ExampleAppender))
    {
        var type = typeof(GeneralError);
        var field = type.GetField(errorField, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);       
        var error = field?.GetValue(null) as IMyError;
        Parameters = new object[] { error };
    }

    private class ExampleAppender : IOperationProcessor
    {
        private readonly IMyError _error;
        public ExampleAppender(IMyError error)
        {
            _error = error ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(error));
        }

        public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
        {
            var openApiResponses = context.OperationDescription.Operation.Responses;
            openApiResponses.TryAdd(((int)_error.StatusCode).ToString(), new OpenApiResponse());
            var apiResponse = openApiResponses[((int)_error.StatusCode).ToString()];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_error.StatusCode.ToString()))
            {
                apiResponse.Description = _error.StatusCode.ToString();
            }

            apiResponse.Content.TryAdd(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json, new OpenApiMediaType() { Schema = JsonSchema.FromType<MyErrorResponse>() });
            var openApiMediaType = apiResponse.Content[MediaTypeNames.Application.Json];
            openApiMediaType.Examples.TryAdd( 
                _error.Description ?? "",
                new OpenApiExample()
                {
                    Description = _error.Description,
                    Value = new MyErrorResponse(_error.Message)
                });
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

[follow the OpenApiOperationProcessorAttribute](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.Annotations/OpenApiOperationProcessorAttribute.cs)

[NSwag Tutorial: Implement a custom operation processor to define ReDoc code samples](http://NSwag%20Tutorial:%20Implement%20a%20custom%20operation%20processor%20to%20define%20ReDoc%20code%20samples)

Answer (score 0):

You can the `SwaggerResponse` attribute like this:

```
[HttpGet("")]
[SwaggerResponse(200, "Myfile content", typeof(MyFile))]
[SwaggerResponse(404, "Could not find file", typeof(MyFile))]
public async Task<IActionResult> YouAction()
```

It will document 2 possible reponse status codes: `200` and `404`.
You can apply as many of those attributes as you wish

Comment: Sorry about this ,
but , i can't set the same HttpStatus code , can i ?

like this
```C#
[SwaggerResponse(404, "Myfile content", typeof(MyFile))]
[SwaggerResponse(404, "Could not find file", typeof(MyFile))]
```